# Excel read cell is empty?

Tags: c#, excel

Hey guys my Problem is when i read the cell and in the cell is nothing i have an error how can i check that?

```
var aExcel = sh.Cells[26, 2].Value.ToString();
 double test = Convert.ToDouble(aExcel);
```

and a other question how can i read more cells ? because my code is so long ...

```
var aExcel = sh.Cells[26, 2].Value.ToString();
var bExcel = sh.Cells[27, 2].Value.ToString();
var cExcel = sh.Cells[28, 2].Value.ToString();
var dExcel = sh.Cells[29, 2].Value.ToString();
var eExcel = sh.Cells[30, 2].Value.ToString();
var fExcel = sh.Cells[31, 2].Value.ToString();
double test1 = Convert.ToDouble(aExcel);
double test2 = Convert.ToDouble(bExcel);
double test3 = Convert.ToDouble(cExcel);
double test4 = Convert.ToDouble(dExcel);
double test5 = Convert.ToDouble(aExcel);
```

Comment: I use using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Comment: *I use using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;* - you can avoid this by using something like EPPlus

Comment: A loop seems appropriate with an array to collect the data in

Comment: *i have an error* - always, always give the exact error text. It's the most helpful debugging info you can give us. Without it, saying "there was an error" is like calling up your mechanic and saying "my car is making a noise"

Comment: This tripping via string may be unreliable. Use the debugger to inspect the types of data you have already got in `sh.Cells[26, 2]` - e.g. put `sh.Cells[26, 2].GetType()` in the immediate window - if it's already a double, then tripping through string is unwise; just do a direct cast

Comment: Saying the car makes a noise is a debug in my opinion. But anyway, the exact error is not hard to understand here. He tries to convert an empty cell to double. That will create an error. It's not hard to understand why and it's an easy fix.

Comment: my error is when i read the cell and in the cell is nothing and i converte the cell in a double my programm end the function thats it , when a number in the cell then read the other cells thats it

Comment: but guys do you have a example code for read more cells in a coloum and then converte in a double ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your second question here is example code:

```
List<Double> datas = new List<Double>();

int excelStartRow = 26;
int excelEndRow = 21;


for (int i = excelStartRow; i <= excelEndRow; i++)
{
    var aExcel = sh.Cells[i, 2];
    if (aExcel != null)
    {
       double value = Convert.ToDouble(aExcel.Value.ToString());
        datas.Add(value);
    }

}
```

Comment: thx you dude ! this is perfect but can you example me how to put from one datas list in a textbox ?

Comment: maybe so                textbox.text = datas[2].ToString();?

Comment: okay i have this thx you man !!!!! so much :)

Comment: okay i have a problem when i read 3 cells and one is empty i spring back to main code why ?

Comment: i read 3 cells one have 1:0,33 2:0,77 3:(Nothing)

Comment: when ich start then have datalist 1: (0,33) 2:(0,77) and then they read the third cell they go to if and the programm will the cell with nothing in a double but why, in the cell is nothing

Answer (score 0):

You can check like this:

```
 if(sh.Cells[26, 2] != null)
{
//do something
}
```

code:

```
double test;
var aExcel = sh.Cells[26, 2];
if(aExcel != null){
test = Convert.ToDouble(aExcel.Value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: for your second question you can use for loop and you can add your values to array or list

Comment: this is great thx you :)

Comment: gurkan do you have a simple example code ?